# Signal FFT conversion problem

Tags: matlab, fft

I got the time domain signal from experimental work as per below. The blue is x-direction,green is z-direction and red is y-direction.

[image]

When i convert the signal into FFT using MATLAB, I got as per below.

[image].

The problem is, the peak should happen in z-direction(Ch3) but happen in x-direction(ch1). The coding as per below:

```
clc;
y1 = Ch1;
y2= Ch2;
y3 = Ch3;
N=6678;
Fs=512;

%Plot FFT Moving Vehicle signal Ch1
NFFT1 = 2^nextpow2(N);
Y1 = fft(y1,NFFT1)/N; % the division by N is to scale the amplitude
f_plot = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT1/2+1); % vector of frequencies for the plot
subplot(311), plot(f_plot,2*abs(Y1(1:NFFT1/2+1))) % multiplicated by 2 to recover the energy related
% to the negative frequencies since in this way only half spectrum is plotted
title('FFT Moving Vehicle Ch1');
xlabel('Frequency [Hertz]');

%Plot FFT Moving Vehicle signal Ch2
NFFT2 = 2^nextpow2(N);
Y2 = fft(y2,NFFT2)/N; % the division by N is to scale the amplitude
f_plot2 = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT1/2+1); % vector of frequencies for the plot
subplot(312), plot(f_plot2,2*abs(Y2(1:NFFT2/2+1))) % multiplicated by 2 to recover the energy related
% to the negative frequencies since in this way only half spectrum is plotted
title('FFT Moving Vehicle Ch2');
xlabel('Frequency [Hertz]');

%Plot FFT Moving Vehicle signal Ch3
NFFT3 = 2^nextpow2(N);
Y3 = fft(y2,NFFT3)/N; % the division by N is to scale the amplitude
f_plot3 = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT3/2+1); % vector of frequencies for the plot
subplot(313), plot(f_plot3,2*abs(Y3(1:NFFT3/2+1))) % multiplicated by 2 to recover the energy related
% to the negative frequencies since in this way only half spectrum is plotted
title('FFT Moving Vehicle Ch3');
xlabel('Frequency [Hertz]');
```

For information,when the sensor do the measurement,the reading for y-direction will fall at-1 to 1 G due to the gravity.

Is there anything I need to do before convert it into FFT? Shift maybe?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The FFT shows the frequency content of your signal, shifting it will not move the peak from the x to the z

Comment: Just to better understand what you are trying to do: what is the reason why you are expecting the peak in the z direction instead of the x one?